# Heroku says Cannot GET / after deploying node-app. Works on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I deployed a NODE-Express backend on Heroku (with ClearDB Add-on). It works fine on localhot but on heroku, It says:

"Cannot Get /"

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn6sA.png)

Attaching few lines of code. Please help.

**index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import multer from "multer";

const app = express();
const PORT = 8800;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, "../client/public/upload");
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
},
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {
const file = req.file;
res.status(200).json(file.filename);
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT, () =\> {
console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

**db.js**

```
import mysql from "mysql"

export const db = mysql.createConnection({
host:"eu-cdbr-west-03.cleardb.net",
user:"b06f-----",
password: "72a------",
database:"heroku_21b3dee9ef-----"
})
```

Comment: You do not have a handler for "GET /" `app.get('/', ...` so if you say this works on localhost the chances are it is some other app handling that. Definitely not this one.

Comment: @Molda, if another app is listening on 8800 then Express should not start

Comment: @pierpy i agree 100%. I assume there are frontend and backend apps running on different ports.